# Show Thumb of Range Input only after click on track [visual analog scale]

Tags: javascript, html, css, range

I would like to modify a range input to resemble a visual analog scale.
The most important aspect is that the thumb should be hidden untill a first input is given on the range by clicking on the track.

Is there a way to hide the thumb and only show it whn the track is clicked?

Comment: Yes. Please share the relevant part of your code so we can look into it.

Comment: It's a simple range input: <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1.0" value="50" name="NA01" class="slider">

Comment: MoDe, I do not know what your track is. You need to invest some time in order to properly ask your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

use onclick event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

and then style your range:

https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

Comment: Thanks! How can I referene input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb, input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb and input[type=range]::-ms-thumb in JS?

Comment: @MoDe inputs with [type=range]:

const ranges = document.getElementsByTagName('input').filter(input=>input.type=='range')



about working with pseudo-classes:
https://www.quora.com/Can-I-add-the-hover-pseudo-class-to-an-element-using-JavaScript?share=1

and

https://zzz.buzz/2016/06/16/working-with-pseudo-classes-in-javascript/

Comment: You can add an autoprefixer it will make your life easier on this point

Comment: @Allure Won't this affect the whole range input and not only the thumb?

Comment: @MoDe just work with pseudo-classes like ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, how to do that is explained here: https://zzz.buzz/2016/06/16/working-with-pseudo-classes-in-javascript/     and here: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-add-the-hover-pseudo-class-to-an-element-using-JavaScript?share=1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! Solution:

```js
    function activatevas(id){
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('notclicked');
    }
```

```css
    input.notclicked[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    input.notclicked[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    input.notclicked[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1.0" value="50" name="NA01" id="NA01" class="slider notclicked" onclick="activatevas('NA01')">
```